# Can I equip my survivors in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

I have plenty of spare armour etc - can I trade it to my survivors and have them actually use it?

Same for Weapons too, also do certain people have better skills with certain weapons?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can talk to them and trade them items via the trade conversation topic.

You can force them to equip something by hovering over the item, and press (<kbd>T</kbd> on PC, Triangle on PS4, and Y on Xbox) to have them equip it.

edit:  PS4 button credit djsmiley2k

edit2: XB button credit VanBuzzKill

Comment: Yup thanks :)

Just noticed you can hit triangle to make them equip it on PS4 :)

Comment: It's Y on Xbox as well.

Comment: I've had them switch back to their original equipment before, even when it was inferior. Removing the original equipment seemed to fix this. Also note that you can command a companion to wear a suit of power armor, and that they don't drain the fusion core.

Comment: I'm having issues with forcing Nick to equip a different weapon.  I force him to equip a different pistol, but once combat starts he switches back.  There's no entry in his inventory for the pistol he carries so I can't remove it and force him to use the one I gave him.  Is this just a part of the game?

Comment: @sommerjj You may have to pickpocket it from him to get it out of his inventory. There were several NPCs like that in Skyrim, which the engine is similar for. You'll need the pickpocket perk to steal weapons though, which i think is the third of that perk.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up using console commands to remove the pistol from his inventory as I'm playing on PC.  I used `inv` to get the ID of his pistol and `removeitem XXXXX` to remove it

Comment: Ugh, you have to press something to have them equip it? I gave all my dwellers weapons and armor. I only figured that I could take their equipped weapon and they would equip what other weapons they had (ones I gave them). I've been going on with them all not having armor for a while...

Comment: hmm this has been going on since long with me. I am giving an advanced shotgun to people like Cait and Hancock. And a laser pistol to Nick, all depending on their default equipped icons (maybe a pistol fellow can't do missiles lol). But they dont use it! I equip them so many times over and over. Only thing left is to spare them ammo :(

Comment: @Dragonborn They require ammo. Without it, they'll revert to their defaults.

Comment: I got it! Cait was nice enough to say 'If you find some ammo share with me' lol

Answer (score 1):

Mainly this is the main time spending as the building the settlement - to equip your settlers with weapons and armor. And every person you interact as the settler or companion could wear armor and hold the weapon you can give to. Please do not forget ammo. Meanwhile for settlers just several pieces means unlimited ammo during the attack. 

There is one more idea - to equip better your guards with armor and weapon which means settlers assigned with guard posts. But I want to say that in real game guard posts do not play the important role outside of the defence score - the first settlers run to fight usually are farmers in my settlements.

About skills - there is no information or confirmations about any skills between the settlers - so they will use any weapon without any additional advantages. About companions the situation is other - they grow will levels, they have perks so for MacCready it is Killshot and it means that more clever to equip him with the guns.